# partial fill a SVG background

Tags: jquery, svg, fill

New to using SVG.

Is it possible to partially fill an SVG background on a mouse event using Jquery?

The code below fills the entire SVG. Im just curious if you can fill maybe 5% of that at a time?

so for example:

```
   $('#button').on('click', function(){
   circle1animate();
   });


   function circle1animate(){
       $('#circle1im').css('fill','#000');                          

    }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GregWebBandit/y72Hx/1/)

Thanks

Comment: I envisioned linear filling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `linearGradient` in the SVG.

In the SVG:

```
<linearGradient id="grad">
    <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="red"/>
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="transparent"/>
</linearGradient>
```

and in the Javascript:

```
$('#grad stop').attr('offset',offset+'%');
```

Like this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/y72Hx/7/).

Comment: ahh, very cool. Did not know about linearGradient. Thank you, Im going toe xperiment with this a bit.